# problem of loading a package at emacs startup

Tags: package

1. According to [Emacs Eclim](https://github.com/senny/emacs-eclim), I added the following to `~/.emacs.d/init.d` for `emacs-eclim`:

   ```
   (require 'eclim)
   (global-eclim-mode)

   ; If you want to control eclimd from emacs, also add:
   (require 'eclimd)
   ```

   The output of `emacs -nw --debug-init` is:

   ```
   Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-error "Cannot open load file" "eclim")
     require(eclim)
     eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/tim/.emacs.d/init.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 4117
     load-with-code-conversion("/home/tim/.emacs.d/init.el" "/home/tim/.emacs.d/init.el" t t)
     load("/home/tim/.emacs.d/init" t t)
     #[0 "^H\205\262^@     \306=\203^Q^@\307^H\310Q\202;^@ \311=\204^^^@\307^H\312Q\202;^@\313\307\314\315#\203*^@\316\202;^@\313\307\314\317#\$
     command-line()
     normal-top-level()
   ```
2. If I add the following line at the beginning:

   ```
   (add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/emacs-eclim-20140809.207/")

   (require 'eclim)
   (global-eclim-mode)

   ; If you want to control eclimd from emacs, also add:
   (require 'eclimd)
   ```

   The output of `emacs -nw --debug-init` is:

   ```
   Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-error "Cannot open load file" "s")
     require(s)
     byte-code("\300\301!\210\300\302!\210\303\304\305\306\307\310%\210\311\312\313\314\315\316\307\304&^G\207"
   [require etags s custom-declare$
     require(eclim)
     eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/tim/.emacs.d/init.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 4115
     load-with-code-conversion("/home/tim/.emacs.d/init.el" "/home/tim/.emacs.d/init.el" t t)
     load("/home/tim/.emacs.d/init" t t)
     #[0 "^H\205\262^@     \306=\203^Q^@\307^H\310Q\202;^@ \311=\204^^^@\307^H\312Q\202;^@\313\307\314\315#\203*^@\316\202;^@\313\307\314\317#\$
     command-line()
     normal-top-level()
   ```
3. If I instead add a different line at the beginning, it works without
   error:

   ```
   (package-initialize)

   (require 'eclim)
   (global-eclim-mode)

   ; If you want to control eclimd from emacs, also add:
   (require 'eclimd)
   ```
4. If I add both lines at the beginning, it also works:

   ```
   (add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/emacs-eclim-20140809.207/")
   (package-initialize)

   (require 'eclim)
   (global-eclim-mode)

   ; If you want to control eclimd from emacs, also add:
   (require 'eclimd)
   ```

I wonder what the two lines I added do, and why they can work or not work? Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your problem is that the package `eclim` as a dependency on the package `s`, so when you require eclim, you need to have `s` in your `load-path`. `package-initialize` ensure that every installed package are in you `load-path`, and load them too, so:

- you don't need to require eclim when you call package-initialize
- you need to add s to the load path if you don't call package-initialize

As you have installed those extension using package, better (and simpler) to use package-initialize.

Comment: Are you saying `(package-initialize)` is to replace `require` and `load-path`?

Comment: Yes. Well I don't know the specific for eclim, but normally a package installed through elpa don't need any load-path tangling nor require.

Comment: (1) Is "installed through elpa" same as "installed by package.el"? (2) what about those packages installed manually? Do they still need load-path and require?

Comment: (1) Well, I should have said installed by package.el, as the source might be something else than elpa. (2) Short answer: probably not, package-initialize is for package installation known by package.el, and I don't known how package.el know how to initialize them.

Comment: Thanks. I asked " Do they still need load-path and require?", and what do you mean by "probably not"?

Comment: I've been unclear. I meant that package-initialize probably no nothing of package installed manualy, so you have to add what is needed to load-path, then requiring them.

Answer (score 3):

It simply initializes all packages before running .emacs file. This way, you already have symbol `eclim` created, and you can use function "require" to require it. If you don't add package-initialize, then this package isn't initialized, `eclim` symbol is unbound, and you get situation that you had before :)

Comment: thanks. (1) but in part 1, I followed the emacs-eclim site, why is there no `(package-initialize)`?  (2) why is `(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/emacs-eclim-20140809.207/")` not needed?

Comment: 1) Maybe they assumed you already have it.
2) Because when you install package, some information are given to emacs - like the package path. If you installed some package manually, you would have to provide its path.
Also, I can't comment on other posts since I don't have >50 rep, but I'll answer your question:
https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Package-Installation.html
In short: `require` is used to load package if other code  in .emacs depends on it. A bit like `#include` in C/C++